# Concatenate files from line number onwards

Tags: cat

I have two text files, file_1 and file_2. 
How can I concatenate file_2, from line 20 onwards, with file_1?

Comment: What do you mean by "concatenate"?

Comment: if i do: cat file_1 file_2 if combines both files completely. i don't want to add the entire file_2 to file_1, just from line 20 onwards...

Comment: Then you want something like this: `{ cat file_1; sed 1,19d file_2 } >result`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Use ed, man! !man ed!](https://www.gnu.org/fun/jokes/ed-msg.html)

```
ed -s file_1 <<< $'r !sed -e 1,19d file_2\nwq'
```

- `-s` = [suppress diagnostic output](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ed)
- `<<<` = redirect ed's input to be the following [here-string](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html#Here-Strings)
- `$' ... '` = supply the following quoted string
- `r` = tell ed to read from the following ...
- `!sed -e 1,19d file_2` = command, instead of a file; ask sed to show us everything except lines 1 through 19 (*d*elete them) of file_2
- `wq` = write and quit!

Comment: Also works with `ex` (no need for the `-s` there)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want lines 20 onwards from file_2, followed by file_1's contents. I would do this:

```
( tail -n +20 file_2; cat file_1 ) > file_3
```